# How to write dates shown on screen

Tags: screenwriting, script, scriptwriting

I’m wanting to know how to enter dates that will be shown in text on the screen in a screenplay, I’ve see. Several ways to do it so I wanted clarification, thx for any help

Comment: How to format the date itself, or how to present it in the script?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, both...I want to know the correct way to show dates on screen by formatting them in the script

Comment: Can’t tell you how much I appreciate your guidance on this, there’s 1 million things online but you put me right where I needed to be

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It’s not necessary in the body of a scene to inform us as to the setting, the time of day, or whether it’s an interior or exterior, as this is already known from the scene heading.
>
> If a legend, such as a locale or a date, is to be superimposed upon a scene, then standard format dictates it be placed within quotes and preceded by the word “SUPERIMPOSE:” (in ALL CAPS with a colon):
>
> SUPERIMPOSE: "Washington, D. C. 1989"

http://www.storysense.com/format/description.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way:

SUPER: Date or other information

SUPER can be used whenever something is to be put on top of what's being shown on camera. That is usually, but not limited to, text.

Answer (score -2):

I've seen this many times over the last 3000 scripts or so:

TITLE OVER : BLAH BLAH  1999